# C# get obscure Active Directory Attributes

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to retrieve some obsure Active Directory Attributes:

1. msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor, and
2. terminalservicesprofilepath (in userparameters)

I am having trouble getting to both of them.

For example, for msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor, if I have code similar to the following:

```
DirectoryEntry deresult = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
byte[] bteMailACL =(byte[])deresult.Properties["msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor"].Value;
```

It complains that I cannot cast System.__ComObject to System.Byte[], but I have seen several example that use code similar to the above.

How do I understand these blobs of information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is in `.Value` part of the statement. Not sure how the examples have been doing it but I've noticed that whenever I call an AD Property like that, I always get an array back of which I get index 0 in case of single result items.

just changing the last statment to:

```
    byte[] btwMailACL = (byte[])deresult.Properties["msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor"][0];
```

solves your problem.

*Edit: for production code, please do remember that this can throw a `NullReferenceException` so do check if the property actually returned a value before calling on the index.*

(Tested on my machine and working as above)

Comment: +1. I noticed that too. Some properties usually return several values (e.g. 'member' which lists the members in an AD group). I guess that for consistency reasons, the designers of the API decided that all the values should be an array, even if most of them contain only 1 item.

Comment: I actually like this design (once i got the hang of it) because now I can just use LINQ on it for most of my operations. Thanks for the +1 :)